# How to open SAP Business One Report Viewer Using c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, sapb1

I am creating an add on which will open a Crystal Report from BP Master, there will be a button which will open that. But i am not be able to call the default SAP B1 Report viewrr . Can anybody sugest me that ?

Comment: Have you tried `Application.SBO_Application.ActivateMenuItem("519");` on the button click event?

Comment: Yes, But how can i pass the parameter ?

Comment: Try getting the active form `Application.SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm` and complete the EditText(s). Their ID will always be the same when the parameter form opens and then `oButton.Click()` (after you assign the `oButton` to the Ok button, whose ID will also never change) to accept the parameters.

Comment: It is not a pretty task but this is the approach I take for some time now. With 9.3 I haven't found something prettier on the UI side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static bool Layout_Preview(string ReportName, string First_Parameter)
                {
                    Recordset oRS = (Recordset)SBOC_SAP.G_DI_Company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);
                    oRS.DoQuery("SELECT MenuUID FROM OCMN WHERE Name = '" + ReportName + "' AND Type = 'C'");
                    SAPbouiCOM.Form form = null;
                    if (oRS.RecordCount > 0)
                    {
                        string MenuID = oRS.Fields.Item(0).Value.ToString();
                        SBOC_SAP.G_UI_Application.ActivateMenuItem(MenuID);
                        form = SBOC_SAP.G_UI_Application.Forms.ActiveForm;
                        ((EditText)form.Items.Item("1000003").Specific).String = First_Parameter;
                        form.Items.Item("1").Click(BoCellClickType.ct_Regular);
                        return true; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SBOC_SAP.G_UI_Application.MessageBox("Report layout 'ReportName' not found.", 0, "OK", null, null);
                        return false;
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Could you mark the sample code as the correct answer (even if its yours, it is the proper way to do it)

Comment: Sure I Will Mark & and Thanks For your Help